# How can I enable session affinity by client IP on a kubernetes loadbalancer in GCP

Tags: kubernetes, ftp, google-cloud-platform, load-balancing, google-kubernetes-engine

I have to set up an FTP server in a GCP Kubernetes cluster, and do not know how to route clients so that multiple requests from the same IP to different ports get routed to the same Kubernetes pod.

In the (passive) FTP protocol, the server opens up a new port, and sends the port number to the client. The client then creates a new connection to that port. Hence, I need to ensure that the second request gets routed to the same pod, because only on that pod a server is waiting for a new connection.

I tried a minimal sample with a workload of two pods that do nothing, and have the ports 21, and 30000-30098 exposed. Then, I set up service of type LoadBalancer as follows (reduced to the relevant portions):

```
kind: Service
spec:
    type: LoadBalancer
    sessionAffinity: ClientIP
    loadBalancerIP: IP_OF_LB
    ports:
    - name: ftp-control
      port: 21
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: 21
    - name: pasv-30000
      port: 30000
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: 30000
      # and so on for the remaining ports up to 30098
```

Now I log onto each of the pods with a shell, and I start to listen manually on one port as follows:

```
netcat -l -p 30001
```

Then, I use telnet from my workstation to connect to the IP address of the load balancer.

```
telnet IP_OF_LB 30001
```

This way, I can see which pod gets the incoming connection request.

For a single port, the load balancer always forwards my request to the same pod.

However, when I try several ports, I can see that subsequent requests get routed to different pods, even though the session affinity is set to `ClientIP`.

Is there any setting that I have missed? I assume, that a session affinity by client IP would only use the IP of the client to determine the target pod. However, it looks as if it is using the IP and the port.

Does anyone know if there are more settings that I can try to get the desired behavior?

Comment: Please move your question to [su] (delete here, re-post there). It's [off-topic here](//stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Hello Martin, thanks for the hint. However, I do not see the tags "kubernetes", "google-cloud-platform" on Super User. Do you know if there is a more appropriate page that covers these topics? Maybe this question is more of a devops question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have posted a bug report at Google, and they say it's intended behavior:
[bug report](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/123150342)

I assumed that if I define a Kubernetes service of type load balancer, then the load is balanced on a pod-level. Instead, the load balancer balances traffic on a VM-basis.

Apparently, the traffic is balanced twice. First, the load balancer distributes the traffic to the VMs, and then Kubernetes balances that traffic to different pods.

That means, session affinity will not work for loadbalancers and Kubernetes in the Google Kubernetes Engine.

Answer (score 2):

I can see you configure your service as LoadBalancer type, however it would be troublesome to configure [session affinity](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/configure-backend-service#setting_client_ip_affinity) on it. Therefore, I actually recommend to do the following:

[Backend config](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/configure-backend-service#creating_a_backendconfig) -> [Nodeport service](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/configure-backend-service#creating_a_service) -> [Ingress](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/configure-backend-service#creating_an_ingress)

Please check using [client IP affinity](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/backend-service#client_ip_affinity) and [Backend Configs](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/backendconfig#backendconfig_v1beta1_cloudgooglecom) for more information.

Comment: Hello Galo, thanks for the help. But as far as I see it, I can only configure an Ingress for Kubernetes for http request. I need to forward the data on a TCP level.

Comment: Hello Haplo, that's correct configuring Ingress you need to use HTTP(S) requests. If you need to do it through TCP, I can recommend this documentation on [Session affinity based on Client IP](https://medium.com/@diegomrtnzg/redirect-your-users-to-the-same-pod-by-using-session-affinity-on-kubernetes-baebf6a1733b) where you don't need an Ingress/Proxy between the Kubernetes Service and the client.

Comment: Or there is another option using an [externalTrafficPolicy](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/create-external-load-balancer/#preserving-the-client-source-ip), creating an external LB and preserving the client source IP.

Comment: Hello Galo, thanks again for the help. I have already set the session affinity to Client IP. While I assume that I configured something wrong, this could also be a bug, and I have reported the behavior to Google.

Comment: Hello Haplo. Actually, let me share with you that Session affinity of Client IP only applies as far as the node VM, not the individual pods therein. Also, some of GCP's LBs support Network Endpoint Groups (NEGs), which direct traffic from the LB to pods directly. At this time, neither the Network LB (TCP in your case) nor the Internal LB support NEGs, though.

Comment: In addition, it's possible that the traffic is directed to pods on other node VMs, too. Since from the perspective of the LB, GCP directs traffic to the same node VM (if session affinity is set to client IP), but then Kubernetes performs another layer of load balancing using "iptables", which sends traffic to a pod. That pod might or might not be on the same node VM. Therefore, it looks as this is expected behavior when using a load balancer (LB) with instance group backends. So you did great reporting it to Google, hopefully they can fix/improve it.